# An error of chez-scheme FFI just like because of C Cross-platform

Tags: c, ffi, chez-scheme, mixed-programming

There is a c file

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>


struct termios raw;


int raw_on(void)
{

    if (tcgetattr(0, &raw) == -1)
        return -1;


    raw.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    raw.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    raw.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;


    // raw.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    // raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
    // raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);
    // raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    // raw.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    // raw.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    return tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}
```

And when I call it in chez-scheme

```lisp
> (load-shared-object "./emacs.so")
> (foreign-procedure "raw_on"() int)
#<procedure>
> (define raw-on (foreign-procedure "raw_on"() int))
> (raw-on)
Exception: invalid memory reference.  Some debugging context lost
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
```

When I search it in internet, I find the termios.h is for POSIX terminal, and my OS is Debian.

May I ask why this bug occurs
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Make the struct `static` or move its declaration inside `raw_on`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the C function `raw_on()` you are binding to the Scheme procedure `raw-on` is accessing a global variable `struct termios raw;`. The problem (I think) is that these variables are not allocated for position-independent code (PIC) unless you declare them `static`. Since you must build the `.so` file using `-fPIC` and `-shared` in order for the functions within to be executable by Chez Scheme, you must declare the global variables to be `static` for these memory locations to exist when `load-shared-object` is evaluated.

```
static struct termios raw; // prepend "static" keyword here

int raw_on(void) { ... }
```

Rebuild:

```
cc -fPIC -shared -o ./emacs.so emacs.c
```

After you have rebuilt the `emacs.so` file, try running your Scheme program again, the "invalid memory reference" failure should be gone.